# In Magento 2 How to Override core customer model?

Tags: magento2

I have to override customer ResourceModel's customer.php file in my custom module.

I have tried but its not working.so what is correct way to override Model?
Please help me.

I follow below steps to override Model,

I have my own module called Namespace_Module with a di.xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer" type="Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Customer" />
</config>
```

Then I have created php file,

```
Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Customer.php
```

and try to override core file.but its not working for me.

So plz anyone help me to solve my problem.
thanks.